# Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return milestonetListing.items }" Message: milestonetListing is not defined

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am new to knockout and typescript both. I am creating simple class in typescript with knockout. But when I am running this it shows me all the function s not defined. Might be I am missing some reference.

**Type Script + knockout**

```
module App {
  class MilestoneSummary {
    constructor(summary ? : any) {
      if (summary) {
        this.id = summary.id;
        this.milestoneName = summary.milestoneName;
        this.milestoneDescription = summary.milestoneDescription;
      }
    }

    id: number;
    milestoneName: string;
    milestoneDescription: string;
  }
  export class Milestone {
    constructor(private _appointmentReference: string) {
      super();
      this.loadMilstones();
    }
    milestone = ko.observable < MilestoneSummary > ();
    milestonetListing = new Listing();

    loadMilstones() {
      if (this.isLoading.peek()) {
        return;
      }
      this.isLoading(true);
      var url = App.getApiUrl("Milestone", "Get", App.viewData.appointment.reference);

      Ajax.load(url)
        .done((data) => {
          var milestones = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, (dis) => {
            return new MilestoneSummary(dis);
          });

          this.milestonetListing.items(milestones);
        })
        .always(() => {
          this.isLoading(false);
        });
    }
  }

  var viewModel = new Milestone(App.viewData.appointment.reference);
  App.setViewModel(viewModel);
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<tbody class="no-wrap" data-bind="foreach: milestonetListing.items, select: milestonetListing">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: milestoneName"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

It always give me error milestoneListing is not defined. I tried to add a simple function that I created to show a popup window and bind that to a bind. It also shows as function not defined.

**Am I missing any Ko refrence?**

Comment: Shouldn't the creation of milestoneListing happen inside the `constructor`?

Comment: I don't think so constructor is used only for assinging the values not for creation.

Comment: is `App.setViewModel` defined elsewhere?

Comment: I've made an example fiddle with a much-simplified version of your code just to see whether the structure is a problem. The example works as you'd expect. My best guess is that there's some problem with your `setViewModel`.
Fiddle: http://fiddlesalad.com/typescript/demo-of-typescript-with-knockout

Comment: Thanks Roy, I will look into my setViewModel code and will let you know.

Comment: so as per my code setviewmodel is a generic function that does not except elementid. is this the reason? 
Is this mandatory parameter to pass?

Comment: No, I only had to pass it in my fiddle because of quirks in the fiddle site. Does your `setViewModel` just call `ko.applyBindings`, or does it do anything else?